# Manipulating MFC dialog executable with Java Code

Tags: java, mfc

I have a MFC dialog executable. I don't have any documents about this executable. I want to use Java code to manipulate it (Fill in some values in the input textfield and click a button and then get the result from the output textfiled). Another constraint is that I don't know the detail behind this executable. e.g. the function names and hooks. Can any one help me?

Best Regards,

Zheng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Microsoft UI Automation. This interface is for handicapped persons but you have clear API and it fits for your scenario.